# Why does Android Studio Emulator not run part of my POST request (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, http-post

Hello stackoverflow users,

I am trying to write a post request (sends an SMS) that is called on a button click. The post request has:

One URL Parameter: api_key

One Header: "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Three JSON pairs: ("from", "insert#here"), ("to", "insert#here"), and ("body", "Hello, World")

By sending my POST request to a REST API endpoint URL, I want the SMS to send when the user clicks a button. This is what I have:

```
public class PostSMS extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String>
{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        MainActivity.text.setText("enteredTry");


        URL url = new URL("https://api.apidaze.io/apikey/sms/send?api_secret=apisecret");
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        MainActivity.text.setText("connectionBuilt");


        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        MainActivity.text.setText("connectionEstablished1");
        urlConnection.connect();

        MainActivity.text.setText("connectionEstablished23");

        // Create JSONObject Request
        JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
        jsonRequest.put("from", "1111111111");
        jsonRequest.put("to", "1111111112");
        jsonRequest.put("body", "Hello, World");

        MainActivity.text.setText("jsonArrayConstructed");

        // Write Request to output stream to server
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonRequest.toString());
        out.close();

        MainActivity.text.setText("OutputStream written");

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        String statusMsg = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();

        // Connection success. Proceed to fetch the response.
        if (statusCode == 200)
        {
            InputStream it = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(it);
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(read);
            StringBuilder dta = new StringBuilder();
            String chunks;
            while ((chunks = buff.readLine()) != null)
            {
                dta.append(chunks);
            }
            String returndata = dta.toString();
            return returndata;
        }
    catch (ProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Upon running this code in an OnClickListener, my TextView object (*text* in the code) only shows "connectionEstablished1" in the emulator, so it does not run the rest of the program.

After

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
MainActivity.text.setText("connectionEstablished1");
```

is run,

the program does not run anymore. There are no compile-time errors.

I have the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

permission as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your logs for anything that might be printed from those `catch` blocks. You should not be touching the UI directly from `doInBackground()`; i.e., you shouldn't be calling `MainActivity.text.setText()` there.

Comment: Hi @Mike M. , I am new to Android Studio, so the interface is a little new too. Where can I check my logs from the catch blocks?

Comment: Have a look at [this developer page](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, it's working if you remove MainActivity.text.setText().

As Mike M. pointed out you shouldn't use MainActivity.text.setText() to track progress, you should use [Logging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) for that. If you want to display progress to user you should use onProgressUpdate(String... values) and onPostExecute(String s) that can be overridden in AsyncTask.

Also you could try to [debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) once you get more familiar with Android studio interface, it's easier than checking Logs and StackTraces from catch blocks.

Comment: I logged every so often, and now I am getting a Bad Request run-time error. Do you have a speculation as to why?

Comment: Try sending from and to values as int: jsonRequest.put("from", 1111111111); 
And check your request url (exact api instance and url format).

Comment: I have similar code in Java (in Eclipse) where I used the Apache HTTPClient. I got the program to run there. But upon copying and pasting that code into a method, importing the necessary dependencies, and running, I got the error "Item may not be null," and Item is written in one of the dependency's classes. I will try to do what you said though. I will change the data type for the phone numbers. Hold for further updates.

Comment: Changing the String phone numbers to integers does not work. The url seems fine as well.

Comment: Hello @P. Suvajac, I got it to work thanks to your Logging methods. I figured out that I was using the wrong form of my Apache client, and I had to create a DefaultHttpClient() (even though it is deprecated, but it worked) instead of the connection I had established here.